# Creating tables with enumeration in LaTeX

Tags: tables

I want to create the following table:

[image]

The MWE is as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
  \hline
  % after \\: \hline or \cline{col1-col2} \cline{col3-col4} ...
  Name of the Service & Description & Input & Output \\
  creditAccount & To credit a bank account & \begin{enumerate}\item Account Number \item Amount \end{enumerate} & \begin{enumerate}\item Message – Whether the credit was successful or not \item Current Account Balance
 \end{enumerate} \\
   &  &  &  \\
   &  &  &  \\
   &  &  &  \\
   &  &  &  \\
   &  &  &  \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

What is wrong with my approach?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following provides the desired layout of the table (without colour):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}% Just for this example

\usepackage{tabularx,array,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{N}{@{}>{\stepcounter{enumi}\theenumi.~}l@{}}
\newcolumntype{M}{@{}>{\stepcounter{enumi}\theenumi.~}p{\linewidth}@{}}
\newenvironment{listenv}
  {\setcounter{enumi}{0}% Reset list counter
   \begin{tabular}[t]}
  {\end{tabular}}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ >{\centering\arraybackslash}X *{3}{X} }
  \toprule
  \textbf{Name of the Service} & \textbf{Description} & \textbf{Input} & \textbf{Output} \\
  \midrule
  % Credit Account =====
  creditAccount & To credit a bank account & \begin{listenv}{N}
    Account Number \\ Amount
  \end{listenv} & \begin{listenv}{M}
    Message -- Whether the credit was successful or not \\
    Current Account Balance
  \end{listenv} \\
  % Credit Transaction Details =====
  creditTransactionDetails & To get the details of the last credit transaction & \begin{listenv}{N}
    Account Number
  \end{listenv} & 
  Message -- With the amount last credited in the account \\
  % Debit Account =====
  debitAccount & To debit from a bank account & \begin{listenv}{N}
    Account Number \\ Amount
  \end{listenv} & \begin{listenv}{M}
    Message -- Whether the debit was successful or not \\
    Current Account Balance
  \end{listenv} \\
  % Debit Transaction Details =====
  debitTransactionDetails & To get the details of the last debit transaction & \begin{listenv}{N}
    Account Number
  \end{listenv} &
  Message -- With the amount last debited in the account \\
  % Get Account Balance =====
  getAccountBalance & To get the balance in the account & \begin{listenv}{N}
    Account Number
  \end{listenv} &
  Message -- With the balance in the account \\
  % Get Credit Card Amount =====
  getCreditCardAmount & To get amount spent through credit card & \begin{listenv}{N}
    Account Number
  \end{listenv} &
  Message -- With the amount spent with Credit Card \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

The enumeration is manually inserted using [`array`](http://ctan.org/pkg/array)'s `>{...}` directive. `listenv` automates the process of resetting the `enumi` counter - typically used in the first level of an `enumerate` list.